# Convert list to set in Python 2.7?

Tags: python

I was expecting:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
set(mylist)
```

to produce:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

but instead it produces (**updated**):

```
set([1, 2, 3])
```

How can I produce `(1, 2, 3)`?

UPDATE: It seems I'm being stupid and need a tuple instead. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What version of Python? It produces `{1,2,3}` for me

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question as soon as I submitted it, realised the version was important!

Comment: sigh, why the close vote?

Comment: Try `set([1,2,3]).pop()`

Comment: @Frxstrem that produces `1`.

Comment: It seems, that you want to get a tuple, so do it with `tuple(mylist)`

Comment: So why are you expecting it to produce `(1, 2, 3)`, because that's a *tuple*, not a set.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes you're right, updated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I was an idiot + asked the wrong question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

do you mean tuple? try this

```
>>> tuple(mylist)
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Yes, I mean tuple not set. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
my_list = tuple([1, 2, 3])
print my_list
```